# Automate Running Marklogic Javascript files and code using ML-Gradle task

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, mlcp, ml-gradle

I am trying to automate running Datafix scripts using ml-gradle task. Myscripts sits in Directory like **c:/data/scripts/Release_123**.

Release_123 can also have sub directories and each sub directory will have data fix scripts(**SJS** file) that needed to be executed.

My requirement is to have ml-gradle task which reads code from those files and execute it.

Is there any approach to achieve this.

Comment: This is really a question about how to write a custom Gradle task. You'll need to write a task that will use Groovy or Java code to read directories and files and then make whatever call you need to ML, probably via the ML Java Client. To get going, read the Gradle docs on writing custom tasks - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html .

Comment: Consider rephrasing and retagging this question to target Gradle audience..